# Replace Halogen spot light

Tags: bathroom, light, halogen

I have been trying to replace this spotlight without success. I could not figure out a way to remove it . Any ideas?[image]

Comment: You might list the things you have already tried - the most obvious thing I would say is unscrew the bulb but surely you tried that already?

Comment: Did you try pulling it straight down???

Comment: Please get a sharp, well-lit photo. I can't see any detail in that one.

Comment: Are you trying to replace the entire fixture (based on the condition of the paint on the trim ring, that's entirely reasonable), or just the bulb?

Comment: pull the whole fixture straight down. i know it's scary the first time... it might be stuck, but it's spring loaded and made to be pulled out.

Answer (score 2):

if a GU16 bulb, then you have to push -in- and turn. This is due to the little 'nubs' on the end of the connectors

[image]